# EventStore async calls terminate program

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, eventstoredb

Why do these async calls terminate execution?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionstring = "esdb+discover://127.0.0.1:2113?tls=false";
    var settings = EventStoreClientSettings.Create(connectionstring);
    conn = new EventStoreClient(settings);
    Parse(); 
}

static async void Parse()
{
    var count = await GetEventCount("test@@test");
    // can not reach here ... program ends exit code 0...
}

public static async Task<int> GetEventCount(string streamname)
{
    var l = conn.ReadStreamAsync(Direction.Backwards, streamname, StreamPosition.Start);

    var count = 0; 
    await foreach (var item in l)
    {
        count++; 
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual type of the `var l` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `await` your `async` method. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionstring = "esdb+discover://127.0.0.1:2113?tls=false";
            var settings = EventStoreClientSettings.Create(connectionstring);
            conn = new EventStoreClient(settings);
            await ParseAsync(); 

}
static async Task ParseAsync()
        {
            var count = await GetEventCount("test@@test");
// can not reach here ... program ends exit code 0...

}
    public static async Task<int> GetEventCount(string streamname)
        {
            var l = conn.ReadStreamAsync(Direction.Backwards, streamname, StreamPosition.Start);

            var count = 0; 
            await foreach (var item in l)
            {
                count++; 
            }

            return count;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, you're 99.99% right, I needed Parse().Wait(); because Main() can't be async

Comment: Main can be async, just change it to static async Task Main().

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is that you're not waiting for the completion of `Parse` so the `Main` method just exists before it completes, thus terminating the program. Nothing else in the code cdoes in fact cause a termination.

The first possible solution is to force waiting on the call:

```
Parse().Wait();
```

Using `Wait` directly is often not a good option and is a frequent cause of deadlocks in more complex programs, although used here will be probably fine.

A better solution is make `Main` async too and just use regular `async`/`await` like everywhere else:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionstring = "esdb+discover://127.0.0.1:2113?tls=false";
    var settings = EventStoreClientSettings.Create(connectionstring);
    conn = new EventStoreClient(settings);
    await Parse();
}
```

Both option will cause the call to `Parse()` to wait until completion, thus giving a chance to use its output.